# CakePHP - select from database with condition

Tags: cakephp, multiple-conditions

I have this selector:

```
$this->Table->find('list',array('contain'=>false,'conditions'=>array('status'=>1,'unit_id'=>null,'country_id'=>$countryId,'eday'=>$eday),'fields'=>'id'));
```

And this works perfect. But now i need to have another one i cant find how to do this ;)

I need to select all records from Table but with condition:

```
'eday'>=$eday AND 'eday'<$eday+7
```

Its this posibble in easy way? Maybe this is stupid question but i dont have exp in PHP ;)

Comment: Sorry [code]'eday'>=$eday AND 'eday'<$eday+7 [/code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cakephp the equivalent for `and` condition is
Example: `column1 = 'value' AND column2 = 'value'`

```
'AND' => array(
    'column1' => 'value',
    'column2' => 'value'
)
```

So your query builder would be like this

```
$this->Table->find('list',array(
    'contain' => false,
    'conditions' => array(
        'status' => 1,
        'unit_id' => null,
        'country_id' => $country,
        'AND' => array(
            'eday >=' => $eday,
            'eday <' => ($eday+7)
        )
    ),
    'fields'=>'id'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass an AND array with in your current conditions array :

```
$this->Table->find('list',array('contain'=>false, 'conditions'=>array('status'=>1,'unit_id'=>null,'country_id'=>$countryId,'eday'=>$eday, AND => array( array('eday >=' => $eday) , array( 'eday <' => $eday+7) )), 'fields'=>'id' ));
```

Comment: Nope, thats giving me "AN ERROR OCCURED".

Comment: what kind of error you getting ?? syntax error or database error ??

Comment: Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: Than use only single AND  array in main condition array

Comment: lol your condition not correct `AND => ` there's no such condition as that in cakephp

Comment: you just forgot to wrap your AND to a `'` or `"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this :

```
$conditions['status'] = 1;
$conditions['unit_id'] = null;
$conditions['country_id'] = $countryId;
$conditions['eday >='] = $eday;
$conditions['eday <'] = $eday + 7;

$this->Table
    ->find('list') //either use this
    ->find('all') //or use this
    ->find() //or this
    ->where($conditions)
    ->select(['addFiledsToSelectHere'])
```

This looks more cleaner.